# Laravel 5.2 How to join three table by laravel eloquent model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have three model

```
1. user 
2. course 
3. fee
```

where user model is connected with course table with one to many relationship and course model is connected with fees table with one to one relationship.

the problem is, I have to find sum of all fee's where user selected  the course and there user's completed stauts should be 1. how to write the query for it?

Course Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Course extends Model
{
    protected $table='courses';
    protected $fillable = ['name','date','publication_status'];


    public function fee(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Fee','course_id', 'id');
    }
      public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','course_id','id');
    }
}
```

User Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $table='users';
     protected $fillable=['name','email','phone','course_id'];



          public function courses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Course','id','course_id');
    }
}
```

fee Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Fee extends Model
{
        protected $table='fees';
    protected $fillable = ['fee','course_id'];

    public function course()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Course', 'course_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

if anybody know the solutions, please provide one.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can find the user first:

```
if(User::find($id)->complete_status == 1){
    $user = User::find($id);
}
```

After this you will return all courses of this user:

```
$courses = $user->courses;
```

And finally you'll implement a foreach statement to return each courses fee:

```
foreach($courses as $course){
    $feeSum += $course->fee->value;
}
```

A example to pass your fee sum to view:

```
return view('view_path' , compact('feeSum'));
```

Suposing that $feeSum is in the same function that return view statement.

After return the variable, in your view file you'll add this for example:

```
<label>{{ $feeSum }}</label>
```

Comment: But I want to redirected to revenuedetails page.
How do I access $id?

Comment: You have to send you fee's array to your view, and in view file you can try this: @foreach($array_name as $row) <label>{{ $row->id }}</label> @endforeach

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using pivot-like relationships.

Your **User model** could have something like:

```
# Get the fees for a user:
public function fees()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Fees', 'fees', 'courses', 'course_id', 'course_id')
                ->withPivot('iterate', 'fields', 'here', 'to', 'pass', 'on')
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

The code above has not been tested at all, but I'm pretty sure the *hasMany* / *belongsToMany* methods allow for linking several tables in a relationship.